# How to get the current year using css?

Tags: css, date

I was appending copyright message to web page while printing, i have used following code

```
@media print
{
    .page:after
    {
        content: "© 2013 Copyright message";
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Is there any default way to get the current year using css?

Comment: I don't think its possible with CSS.

Comment: I cant see the reason that you dont want to use js

Comment: @laaposto Actually i append those content to printing page. So only am asking for css

Comment: @PandiyanCool +1 It's an interesting question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can attach date to the div itself (`data-date`) and generate it on server side/javascript. Then in CSS you can grab it (`attr(data-date)`) and attach to content. It would look like this (sorry, untested)

```
content: "©  " attr(data-date) " Copyright message";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

http://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr

Answer (score 5):

```js
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById("spanYear").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

```html
Copyright 1900-<span id="spanYear"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure CSS this is not possible. You would need to use Javascript `getDate()` function for this, or print it into your page if you have any server-side scripting capabilities available.

You could add an extra element in your HTML, populate date(year) with JS, hidden by default with `display:none` and set `display:block` in your print only CSS.

If you really want to stay away from Javascript then you could perhaps use a variable in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), but you would still need to update that each year!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible but you can give it a try.
If you are familiar with Sass and compass (a preproccesor and its compiler to css) or if you willing to learn you can try something like this

`def SomeController`

`#...`

`def create`

```
@model = Model.new params[:model]
```

`@model.date_field_name = Time.now`

`if @model.save`

```
  # whatever should be done if validation passes or

  redirect_to @model

else

  # whatever should be done if validation fails or

  render :new

end`
```

`end`
  `#...`
`end`

[the same problem solved in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896165/current-date-in-rails-form)

What I mean is that, since Sass is builted on Ruby on rails 
you can write few lines in ruby and import the file in the project.
After the compilation you will end with only a css file.
Hope I helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Apache web server you can use SHTML (active) 
I use one footer file for thousands of pages. Well here goes:
`<!--#include virtual="myfile.txt" -->` 
You could use a url there as well.
`<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL"--> or <!--#echo var="DATE_GMT"-->` or the 
`<!--#config timefmt="%A, %d %B %Y"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL"-->` there are slew of commands for you to use but on my websites I like the first form.
In this way I can make the contents virtual. so my scheme is filename.inc
the problem is if you wish to then insert a new include it will not work, unless you call it html/shtml. to get the year automated now use first form. and on you server in that file you can now call a JavaScript/PHP/whatever to get your dates.

enjoy
Cris
BTW here is my main page using shtml:

```
<body>
<!--#config timefmt="%A, %B %d %Y"-->
<table WIDTH=100% HEIGHT=20% BORDER=1>
<tr HEIGHT=20%><td><center><font SIZE="+5"><b>Phoenix Trading</b></font><br>
<font SIZE="+2"><i>Buy, Sell, Trade... One to a Million</i></font>
</center></td></tr>
</table>

<table WIDTH=100% HEIGHT=70% BORDER=1>
<tr HEIGTH=70%>
<td width=200 align="left" valign="top">
<center><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL"--></center><br>
<p><!--#include virtual="menus/menu.inc"--></p>
</td>
<td valign=center><br>
<!--#include virtual="include/main.inc"-->
</td></tr></table>
<!--#include virtual="include/footer.inc"-->
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Years ago I “solved” the copyright update issue with Visual Basic (VBScript), but unfortunately, it’s really a mute point because VB seems to only work in older versions of Internet Explorer (This VB code does not even appear in Internet Explorer 11, and I just realized that by reading my footer which is something I obviously tend to neglect! lol).

Here's my VB code if that helps but what one really needs is a filter to hide it on any browser other than IE (…well, IE 11 made that a mute point, too! lol). Does anyone have some quick fix for that--but I assume the same one “…would need to use JavaScript” coding wild goose chase issue applies? kml ;-) Thanks.

```
<script language="vbscript">
    document.write ("Copyright &copy; 1994-" + cstr(DatePart("YYYY", Now())) + " COPYRIGHT HOLDER NAME. All Rights Reserved.")
</script>
```

Comment: The question was about CSS, nobody mentioned VB.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have searched for css answer.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, here is some example:

HTML

```
<h1>Copyright Year in CSS</h1>
<h2>Set the current year using EQCSS</h2>
<footer>Your Name</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
@element 'footer' {
  $this:before {
    content: '© eval("new Date().getFullYear()")\ '
  }
}
```

This example was taken from here: https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/pen/Qybgmo

Comment: This depends on a JS library called EQCSS to work. This isn't pure CSS.